# How can I compress my local file and copy to remote machine and the uncompress?

Tags: ssh

I can do every single step:
1, compress file using tar
2, copy to remote machine using scp
3, login remote machine using ssh, need password
4, uncompress the file
but, I want to write a single script to do the work, anyone suggestion?

Comment: `tar` does not compress. It just puts multiple files together into one single file, but without any compression. You use e.g. `gzip` or `bzip` to compress a `tar` file. The `tar` command is still necessary though, because those compression algorithms can only operate on single files.

Comment: I use the `-z` flag to compress

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use `rsync` to do that? From the computer were you want to get the file

```
rsync myuser@192.168.0.1:/home/myuser/mydir/myfile myfile
```

will move the file over the two computers, taking care of the transportation. You can even pass recursively (`-r`) if you want to sync the whole directory.

Regarding compressing the data, you can obtain it via `-z` option, but keep in mind that if your connection is fast and your CPU is slow (mobile devices) you will have better performances just transferring the data without compressing them.

--

Following the comment below, I suggested to look into fabric (http://www.fabfile.org/), which will give you the ability to operate on a server by remote.

so for example as a template you could:

```

```
from fabric.api import run

def kill_and_replace():
    run('killall myserverprocess')
    run('cp mynewfile myoldfile')
```

```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't said clearly, Acutally, it's not just sync files, I need login to remote machine to kill the server program, and then replace the files it needed, and then restart it, so it will be updated